# COUNT (DISTINCT column_name) Discrepancy vs. COUNT (column_name) in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm running into a problem that's driving me nuts.
  When running the query below, I get a count of *233,769*

```
 SELECT COUNT(distinct  Member_List_Link.UserID)  
 FROM Member_List_Link  with (nolock)   
 INNER JOIN MasterMembers with (nolock)  
     ON Member_List_Link.UserID = MasterMembers.UserID   
  WHERE MasterMembers.Active = 1 And
        Member_List_Link.GroupID = 5 AND 
        MasterMembers.ValidUsers = 1 AND 
        Member_List_Link.Status = 1
```

But if I run the same query *without* the distinct keyword, I get a count of *233,748*

```
 SELECT COUNT(Member_List_Link.UserID)  
 FROM Member_List_Link  with (nolock)   
 INNER JOIN MasterMembers with (nolock)
   ON Member_List_Link.UserID = MasterMembers.UserID   
 WHERE MasterMembers.Active = 1 And Member_List_Link.GroupID = 5 
  AND MasterMembers.ValidUsers = 1 AND Member_List_Link.Status = 1
```

To test, I recreated all the tables and place them into temp tables and ran the queries again:

```
  SELECT COUNT(distinct  #Temp_Member_List_Link.UserID)  
  FROM #Temp_Member_List_Link  with (nolock)   
  INNER JOIN #Temp_MasterMembers with (nolock)
    ON #Temp_Member_List_Link.UserID = #Temp_MasterMembers.UserID   
  WHERE #Temp_MasterMembers.Active = 1 And 
        #Temp_Member_List_Link.GroupID = 5 AND 
        #Temp_MasterMembers.ValidUsers = 1 AND 
        #Temp_Member_List_Link.Status = 1
```

And without the distinct keyword

```
  SELECT COUNT(#Temp_Member_List_Link.UserID)  
  FROM #Temp_Member_List_Link  with (nolock)   
  INNER JOIN #Temp_MasterMembers with (nolock)
    ON #Temp_Member_List_Link.UserID = #Temp_MasterMembers.UserID   
  WHERE #Temp_MasterMembers.Active = 1 And 
        #Temp_Member_List_Link.GroupID = 5 AND 
        #Temp_MasterMembers.ValidUsers = 1 AND 
        #Temp_Member_List_Link.Status = 1
```

On a side note,  I recreated the temp tables by simply running (`select * from Member_List_Link into #temp...`)

And now when I check to see the difference between COUNT(column) vs. COUNT(distinct column) with these temp tables, I don't see any!

So why is there a discrepancy with the original tables?

I'm running SQL Server 2008 (Dev Edition).

UPDATE - Including statistics profile

PhysicalOp column only for the first query (without distinct)

```
NULL
Compute Scalar
Stream Aggregate
Clustered Index Seek
```

PhysicalOp column only for the first query (with distinct)

```
NULL
Compute Scalar
Stream Aggregate
Parallelism
Stream Aggregate
Hash Match
Hash Match
Bitmap
Parallelism
Index Seek
Parallelism
Clustered Index Scan
```

Rows and Executes for the 1st query (without distinct)

```
1   1
0   0
1   1
1   1
```

Rows and Executes for the 2nd query (with distinct)

```
Rows    Executes
1   1
0   0
1   1
16  1
16  16
233767  16
233767  16
281901  16
281901  16
281901  16
234787  16
234787  16
```

Adding OPTION(MAXDOP 1) to the 2nd query (with distinct)

```
Rows Executes

1           1
0           0
1           1
233767          1
233767          1
281901          1
548396          1
```

And the resulting PhysicalOp

```
NULL
Compute Scalar
Stream Aggregate
Hash Match
Hash Match
Index Seek
Clustered Index Scan
```

Comment: You do understand the differences between COUNT and COUNT DISTINCT, right?

Comment: COUNT DISTINCT should have equal or less hits than COUNT.

Comment: Yes, I do (@JohnFx). But if you read my question, that's not where the problem is. Additionally, from the above queries, the query with the distinct keyword yields a higher number. And this discrepancy does not exist when the data is moved to temp tables.

Comment: My point exactly, @Jeremy. Something isn't right and I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Is this database in use by other processes? I could imagine so with 240 thousand members...

Comment: Up shot being distinct returns more rows than the count... you have spooky extra rows... Distinct should always be <=count.

Comment: This is the second time I hear this today. Weird. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611829/higher-query-result-with-the-distinct-keyword/7612131#7612131

Comment: Android and SO are not playing nice. What do you get when you do your temp tables without nolock? Surely these tables are static...

Comment: IF you run this without the `with (nolock)` hint do you get different results?

Comment: @Adrian - You were right about the last question not having enough data. To avoid congestion in one post, I created a new one here instead.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss. No difference if nolock is removed.

Comment: Here is some discussion you may enjoy: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss. The general consensus here seems to be going in that direction, so this post should be interesting.

Comment: @Ray - Can you just post the whole table "as is" so we can see the row counts etc. (obviously anonymise any object names as required). Also If you add `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to the `distinct` query what result do you get?

Comment: Very tricky to include the entire table (and a lot of work to anonymise the objects). Just posted the rows and executes. Does this help further?

Comment: @Ray - What **result** did you get with `MAXDOP 1`? Did adding it change the result?

Comment: I've posted it as well (edited the question). And yes, it did change the result.

Comment: Sorry... Just understood your question. The result is the same as before.

Comment: The rows and executes for your first query don't look possibly correct. How can they just be `0` and `1`?

Comment: I just copied it directly from the results window. I might have to consult with a sr. dba. But what are you thinking? I can discuss this internally and post an answer if we find it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3938/discussion-between-ray-and-martin-smith)

Comment: @Ray - Not thinking any specific at the moment. But without some concrete information to go off difficult to come up with any theory!

Comment: Sometimes awfully outdated statistics may affect results from the query, specially if your doing index seeks instead of clustered index seeks, UPDATE STATISTICS would have fixed it. It didn't so the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Sorry @MartinSmith. Let me take this up internally and I will definitely keep this post updated with what I'm able to find out. This is a production DB, so I'm sure it'll make everyone want to figure this out as it's affecting the outputs in one of our apps

Comment: @MartinSmith the zeros are for COMPUTE SCALAR, that's normal. The weirdest of all is the resulting HASH MATCH aggregate is 233767, 2 less than the actual result.

Comment: @Ray - What happens if you run `SELECT COUNT(distinct  Member_List_Link.UserID), COUNT(Member_List_Link.UserID)`?, do you still get different results?

Comment: @ThiagoDantas - But clearly there must be a greater number of rows somewhere that is in the input into this. It can't possibly be all `0` and `1`

Comment: @MartinSmith the showplan for the simple COUNT(*) probably doesn't have the join, it is probably just going for the statistics.
Ray can you extract query plan XML and link it here?

Comment: @Thiago - `set statistics profile on` has columns for `Rows` and `Estimate Rows`. The former is actual.

Comment: @Ray - BTW Just to be clear by pasting tables I meant the complete tabular output of `set statistics profile on`. This is trivial to copy and paste into your question and is only a few rows of data so really shouldn't be remotely too difficult to anonymize. Specifically if the result of the first query isn't randomly tuncated is it accessing an indexed view?

Comment: Dumb question - did you run a DBCC CHECKDB on the database?  Just guessing in case there's a problem with a corrupted index.  We could also test around that by forcing a particular index to be used, too.

Comment: Are we to assume from the lack of action on this question that you found the explanation?

Answer (score 4):

FROM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx
NOLOCK Is equivalent to READUNCOMMITTED. For more information, see READUNCOMMITTED later in this topic.

READUNCOMMITED will read rows twice if they are the subject of a transation- since both the roll foward and roll back rows exist within the database when the transaction is IN process.

By default all queries are read committed  which excludes uncommitted rows

When you insert into a temp table the select will give you only committed rows - I believe this covers all the symptoms you are trying to explain

Answer (score 1):

I think i have got the answer to your question but tell me first is userid a primary key in your original table ?

if yes,then CTAS query to create temp table would not copy any primary key of original table ,it only copy NOT NULL constraint that is not a part of primary key..fine?

now what happened your original table had a primary key so count(distinct column_name) doesnt include tuples with null records and while you created temp tables , primary key doesnt get copied and hence the NOT NULL constraint doesnt get to the temp table!!

is that clear to you?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to reproduce this behaviour, so I'm punching in the dark here:

The WITH (NOLOCK) statement enables reading of uncommitted data. I'm guessing you've added that to not lock anything for your users? If you remove those and issue a

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

Prior to executing the query, you should get more reliable results. But then, the tables may receive locks while executing the query.

If that doesn't work, my guess is that DISTINCT use an index to optimize. Check the queryplan, and rebuild indexes as necessary. Could be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What result do you get with

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT distinct  Member_List_Link.UserID
    FROM Member_List_Link  with (nolock)
    INNER JOIN MasterMembers with (nolock)
      ON Member_List_Link.UserID = MasterMembers.UserID
    WHERE MasterMembers.Active = 1 And
         Member_List_Link.GroupID = 5 AND 
         MasterMembers.ValidUsers = 1 AND
         Member_List_Link.Status = 1
) as m
```

AND WITH:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT distinct  Member_List_Link.UserID
    FROM Member_List_Link  
    INNER JOIN MasterMembers
      ON Member_List_Link.UserID = MasterMembers.UserID
    WHERE MasterMembers.Active = 1 And
         Member_List_Link.GroupID = 5 AND 
         MasterMembers.ValidUsers = 1 AND
         Member_List_Link.Status = 1
) as m
```

Answer (score 0):

Ray, please try the following

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
    SELECT Member_List_Link.UserID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Member_List_Link.UserID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) N
    FROM Member_List_Link  with (nolock)   
    INNER JOIN MasterMembers with (nolock)  
        ON Member_List_Link.UserID = MasterMembers.UserID   
     WHERE MasterMembers.Active = 1 And
           Member_List_Link.GroupID = 5 AND 
           MasterMembers.ValidUsers = 1 AND 
           Member_List_Link.Status = 1
) A
WHERE N = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

when you use count with distinct column it doesn't count columns having values null.

create table #tmp(name char(4) null)

insert into #tmp values(null)

insert into #tmp values(null)

insert into #tmp values("AAA")

Query:- 
1> select count(*) from #tmp
2> go

---

```
       3
```

1> select count(distinct name) from #tmp
2> go

---

```
       1
```

1> select distinct name from #tmp
2> go
 name

---

NULL

AAA

but it works in derived table

1>  select count(*) from ( select distinct name from #tmp) a

2> go

---

```
       2
```

Note:- I tested it in Sybase

Comment: doesn't explain why COUNT DISTINCT would return more than simple COUNT. He could have millions of NULLs, a select distinct would count 1

Comment: Count Column name never include null values in count.. whether you use distinct or not. so even you remove distinct from count and only use count(col_name) it won't count null values row. thats why i used derived table here and selected only one column and used count(*) .

Comment: Neither COUNT(*), COUNT(col) nor COUNT(DISTINCT col) evaluates NULLs