# Why does SELECT DISTINCT return a different number of rows than COUNT(DISTINCT)?

Tags: sql, database, count, distinct, informix

I just noticed something strange on *some* of my Informix SQL columns (in the same table). When I do this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT colName
FROM myTable
```

I get, for example, 40 rows. But when I do

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT colName)
FROM myTable
```

I get a significantly bigger number (like, for example, 300). On some columns it works, however (number of rows and count result are equal). If I do this:

```
SELECT colName
FROM myTable
```

I get the same number of rows that

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
```

gives, which is yet another (much higher) number, nameley the exact number of all rows in the table.

**Why does the number returned from `COUNT (DISTINCT)` and the row-number returned by the regular `SELECT DISTINCT` differ on some columns but not on others?**

Comment: Could your interface be limiting the number of rows being returned?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, I checked this. It also happens on small numbers (like 7 and 10) where the interface should definitley not limit anything.

Comment: What is the count ifyou are using the following query? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY colName`

Comment: @Haneev Then I get the number of rows like on teh regular `SELECT DISTINCT`, but the numbers of each row add up to the value of `COUNT (DISTINCT)`

Comment: How many non-distinct rows get returned in the first example when you remove `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @Chris `SELECT colName FROM myTable` gives me yet another number, an even bigger one (like 1000). (which is just the number of all rows in the table)

Comment: Is your answer in this existing post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613679/count-distinct-column-name-discrepancy-vs-count-column-name-in-sql-server-2

Comment: Are you able to provide steps to reproduce this on a new table with no sensitive data? That would be useful in helping.

Comment: Can you also try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT colName FROM myTable)`?

Comment: I once had similar problem, but with other database. It was using broken index and `REINDEX` helped. Maybe there is similar problem then befere you call IBM helpdesk you can try to `UPDATE STATISTICS`.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT colName)` will only count rows where `colname IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT colName FROM my_table)` just for fun and possible profit. In other news: Your index on `colName` may be broken; can you re-create it?

Comment: I have the same problem, `count(DISTINCT s0_.id)` return `31` result, but `DISTINCT s0_.id` return `26` result, while there is no any duplicate `id` in result and id is not nullable, I also check table and its status is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql) on `COUNT`:

> DISTINCT
>   Specifies that COUNT returns the number of unique **nonnull** values.

`SELECT DISTINCT`, on the other hand, will include null values in the result set.

Not sure if that gets you all the way to a solution, but I suspect the null values have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this on MyAdventureWorks. Seems to be working fine in SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT count(distinct city)
  FROM [MyAdventureWorks].[Person].[Address]
```

575

```
select count(city)
FROM [MyAdventureWorks].[Person].[Address]
```

19614 rows

```
select distinct city
from [MyAdventureWorks].[Person].[Address]
```

575 rows